# change an entire svg using class change

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to change an entire svg by changing the class.The problem is that I don't know for sure how to set a new class to the svg so I tried like this:

```
<script>
function change() {
document.getElementById("hi").setAttribute("className", "Hi Hello")
}
</script>
```

Fiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/orhojkq6/1/
Can someone please tell me if I am wrong somewhere?I am an beginner.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"change an entire svg"_. Is your actual question; _"How do I change an elements class with javascript"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very strange method being used to modify the svg background, but if you want to add a class name to the svg, the easiest method would be to use `classList`

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("hi").classList.add("Hello");
  }, 2000);
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using inline javascript, so I removed it in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/orhojkq6/3/).

Also, it isn't conventional to use capital letters at the start of a class name.